I need help creating a New Column in Power BI
I've been trying to create a new Column in Power BI and I can't seem to get what I need. On this example table I am wanting to see how many times a "user" issued a matching name in the "pay to" Column for different account numbers. For example, in this example "Tim" issued a check to "Sally and Co" two times for different account numbers. I want to be able to see if the user is issuing payments to the same individuals on different accounts.
Example
I've tried this and it works well except for showing me the different accounts. I wrote this and it shows correctly if the same check pay to has been used but if multiple checks are issued on the same account, this will show that. I am more interested in if the same check pay to is used on different account numbers.
FILTER( 'Current Check Information', EARLIER('Current Check Information'[Check Pay To]) = 'Current  Check Information'[Check Pay To]),
'Current Check Information'[Check Pay To])
